How can I solve Integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL constraint failed in Laravel factories
When I try to test two of my models with factories there's an error message that says I'm no setting "type" value.
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: comment_votes.type (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "comment_votes" ("comment_id", "user_id") values (1, 18), (2, 18), (3, 18), (4, 18), (5, 18))

In my comment_votes table have comment_id , user_id and type columns, all of these non nullable.
Schema::create('comment_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('comment_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->string('type');
    $table->timestamps();
});

I tried to test the relationship with Pest using the code below
test('BelongsToMany relationship works', function () {
    $user = User::factory()
        ->has(CommentVote::factory()->count(5), 'votedComments')
        ->create();
    assertCount(5, $user->votedComments);
});


My User model looks like this:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // Rest of the model...

    /**
     * Get the comments where the user has voted.
     */
    public function votedComments(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class, CommentVote::class);
    }
}

My CommentVote model looks like this:
class CommentVote extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'comment_id',
        'user_id',
        'type', // Notice that is included
    ];

    protected static function newFactory(): Factory
    {
        return CommentVoteFactory::new();
    }

    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'type' => CommentVoteType::class,
        ];
    }


    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    public function comment(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }
}

My CommentVoteFactory looks like this:
class CommentVoteFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = CommentVote::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'comment_id' => Comment::factory(),
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'type' => 'positive', // Notice that is included
        ];
    }
}

